# Google spreadsheets: generalize calculating number of nonzero values in a row?

Tags: google-sheets

I am administering quests for a relatively small group in an online game. I want to track who signs up and remove a person from the group if they miss 3 online quests in a row.

Currently I have the following setup:

- column A lists all the member names
- columns G-I specify who has been in which quest. G is the most recent, H next most, I 3rd most.
- column, say, B4 checks if person A4 is in group G. If so, it is 0. If not, it is 1.
- columns C4 and D4 work similarly for if A4 is in column H and I.
- column E4 is the sum of B4 through D4. This is for general tracking participation.
- column F4 is B4 + B4 * C4 + B4 * D4.

F4 is the main one I have a question about. I may, in the future, want to be more lenient and boot people if they missed 4 in a row. It would not be too hard to insert a row. Then (G4, which was F4) = B4 + B4 * C4 + B4 * C4 * D4 + B4 * C4 * D4 * (new E4), which would track if A4 is in the new column J (the 4th-most recent quest.)

This does the job, but is it possible to do anything less hard-coded? How would we generalize to N > 4 without relying on scripts? Is it possible?

ETA: here is a [link to the name-redacted spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EvgW6mYCD-tOnFJpsceMXudrG08UjSoFJsAKqMM9CUs/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Welcome. Please [share a sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311)

Comment: Done. Sorry about that. I avoided an example because I was worried about potential personal information. It should be gone now. Let me know if further refinement/information is needed. Thanks!

Comment: What are your expected results and where should they be?

Comment: Well, I have what I want for the case of 3 rows. I'd like to expand it to N rows, but I'm not sure how to express that without making the spreadsheet messy.

Comment: Make a copy of the spreadsheet, make a copy of sheet1 with expected results in place of your efforts and share it publicly with edit rights. Not just comment access'